# Angular 8: Select first element of ng-content

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to create a multi step form component that needs to display the ng-content.

It should display it not at once but only one per step.

The following code should therefore result in a two step form.

```html
<ion-content>
  <div class="centered">
    <app-multi-step-formular>
      <div>
        <!-- Step One -->
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="password"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <!-- Step Two -->
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="password"/>
      </div>
    </app-multi-step-formular>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

My current approach looks like this:

```html
<div class="multi-step-form">
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Initially the first div is displayed -->
    <ng-content select="div:1"></ng-content>
    <!-- User clicks next, then second div is displayed -->
    <ng-content select="div:2"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <!-- After clicking the next button, the next div from ng-content should be displayed-->
  <button (click)="nextStep()>
    Continue
  </button>
</div>
```

*References*
[The slides from Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) are a good example of what I want to achieve in a technicals POV.

I am really thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you please share your code using some editor, so that it could be more clear what the error is?

Comment: I've edited the code and added comments, I hope it's now clear what I'm trying to achieve. Otherwise please have a look at [Ionic Slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides).

Answer (score 1):

the "clasic" is create a directive,

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[custom-slide]'
})
export class CustomSlideDirective {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Then you only need ask about [ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren)

```
   @ContentChildren(CustomSlideDirective) slides!: QueryList<CustomSlideDirective>;
```

Then, `this.slides.first` is the first slide (be carefully you need use after view init)

Yes, this oblige to write some like

```
   <app-multi-step-formular>
      <div custom-slide>
           ....
      </div>
      <div custom-slide>
           ....
      </div>
    </app-multi-step-formular>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. How would the mutli step form component look like? I mean the HTML part?